# Delete folder after a database column was deleted

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am storing a property details in one database table and the property images in another. upon delete of property i am deleting the images and the property itself from database. but i also need to delete the images from the server. and i have trouble with doing it.. my database with the images looks like this

```
FILE_PATH | PROP_ID
```

and in file path it is stored like this

```
/images/uploads/2016/01/propname/filename.jpg
```

but full path `/var/www/html/images/uploads/2016/01/vsehrdova-6s/vsehrdova-6s-1.jpg`

```
function delete_single_property($id)
{
        $this->db->delete('properties', array('room_id' => $id));
        $this->db->delete('properties_images', array('PROP_ID' => $id));
}
```

Comment: You are storing the filename and not the foldername.. it will be better if you delete each image file inside the folder, you cannot delete the folder unless you store the folder full path within the database..

Comment: @IlanHasanov can you help me with the file deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to delete the folder since you don't store it in the database. i can help you with image file deletion in the server.. This should work:

```
function delete_single_property($id)
{
    $q = $this->db->select('FILE_PATH')->from('properties_images')->where('PROP_ID', $id)->get();
    $dbase_path = $q->result_array();
    $new = array();
    foreach ($dbase_path as $single) {
        $new[] = '/var/www/html' . $single['FILE_PATH'];
    }
    foreach ($new as $file) { // iterate files
        if (is_file($file))
            unlink($file); // delete file
    }
    $this->db->delete('properties', array('room_id' => $id));
    $this->db->delete('properties_images', array('PROP_ID' => $id));
}
```

It will loop all FILE_PATH of a property check if what you storing in the database FILE_PATH is actually exists and a file. and `unlink` simply deletes the file

Comment: He can use dirname() function, which returns the directory of the file.

Comment: It is actually working. and i think deleting the files is better approach than the folder. thnkas

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = '/var/www/html' . dirname($filenameStoredInDB);
if (is_dir($dir))
    rmdir($dir);
```

Comment: how can i combine this to my function

Comment: I have no idea about CodeIgniter